# Will a singleton created in struts action persist?

Tags: java, struts2, singleton, thread-local, struts-action

If I instantiate a Singleton class in a Struts action, will it be persistent for other request firing up that action ?

I mean, if I'm in a Struts action code and I write:

```
Singleton object = Singleton.getInstance();
```

will the object exist when another user fires up the same or another action requiring that object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get your doubt:

**since Struts2 Actions are [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)**, and hence every action, on every request, creates an instance of its object, **will a Singleton behave correctly** ?

From your code it seems you are referring to the [pre-1.5* Singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Eager_initialization):

```
public class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

The answer is **yes**:

> private **static** final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

since `static` "wins" over `ThreadLocal`, and makes it *unique* (instantiated once, then shared).

---

*Note that if you are on Java EE >= 6, there are many ways to handle Singletons better than this, with CDI, EJB3, etc... eg `@Singleton` EJB or `@Singleton` injections.

Comment: Perfect answer, one more doubt, will that object be available in the whole struts app? I mean, i will be available to use it in other action, right?

Comment: Yes, it definitely is

Answer (score 0):

#### A "Single" Instance

A properly implemented `Singleton` will be constructed once within the context of your application, and once created will be re-used within the JVM. The [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) Wikipedia page says (in part),

> In software engineering, the singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.

#### tl;dr

Yes. A `Singleton` is a form of global variable, and thus there will only be one instance shared by all users.